# What can I do to investigate 50% CPU on Interrupts?

Tags: cpu-usage, interrupts

My PC suddenly became very slow.

In my Process Explorer, I noticed that it consistently spends 50% of CPU in "Interrupts" process.

I googled around and found that one possible solution is to go into Control Panel/System and find devices in device manager that have yellow "?" on them... BUT... I have none.

I don't have a ton of hardware on the system, and none of it recently changed:

- 1 SATA HDD (WDC 640GB)
- External DVD-R (which I disconnected).
- No separate video card

It seems to be happening generally correlated to disk access (e.g. when running some program that reads from disk, or even swapping out memory; and going down when there's no programs accessing disk), but I have no definite proof of that.

The only other weird thing that happened - not sure if it was related - is that for the last couple of months, my keyboard sometimes refuses to work - but starts working after a reboot.

What can I do to investigate this issue?

System is home-built AMD E-350 desktop. The issue did NOT occur when it was built around a year+ ago - only started 2-3 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

SOFTWARE:

Last time I had this it was a nasty conflict between some low-level-driver-installing SECURITY SOFTWARE and took me ages to clean-out, but worked once I did. So start looking at that kind of thing. Also rootkits using a fake hardware driver as their attack vector, that comes to mind.

Try looking at how your lowest-level drivers have been updated or corrupted.

Look at your MBR to see if you've been root-kitted or something that conflicts at low level.

Look for hardware damage, and assuming the components are protected inside a case, consider whether the motherboard hasn't received a surge to the chipset etc.

Then try (whilst static-electricity protected) re-seating your HDD cables.

Then go into the BIOS setup, make a note of settings, make sure you get them ALL. Then power-off. Unplug everything from the PC after grounding yourself on the metal chassis, and short the jumper to clear the CMOS (BIOS Settings).

Leave it for 5 minutes (battery in).

Then un-short the jumper (put it back on the other two pins where you found it).

Plug everything back in.

Boot into BIOS. Set the same settings as before.

DO NOT BOOT INTO THE OPERATING SYSTEM UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES BEFORE DOING THE LAST STEP ABOVE.

Then if no joy, try reseating your RAM. (You know how to memtest86 test your RAM, right?)

Also make sure your PSU is capable enough (can appear over time without changing anything).

Make sure your CPU isn't somehow getting heat-damaged whilst you're at it.

Then see if things have improved.

Sometimes the BIOS gets confused (it doesn't help that numerous implementations allow messing with it from within Windows... and UEFI is a JOKE for security, etc).

If not, unplug the HDD, try a clean install to a freshly-blanked spare HDD (I keep an old 80GB lying around for this).

If the issue is replicated, and you're using known-good driver versions, from a clean source and a clean OS install disc... ->

Then work on the basis of damaged hardware (at a microscopic level, probably not visible, and this is the kind of damage that static electricity can do - I've done it about twice in my career).

I believe (I'm no expert) that this can be chipset / CPU damage, but it could be anything in the low-level software/drivers that affects the former's function and makes it APPEAR like there's damage).